# I added a click effect to my calculator keys but when you click one of them the others move too!! Can you help me?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, dom-events, dom-manipulation

Like I've written in the title when you click one of the keys the others in the same column move too. How can I solve this problem? I would like them to stay in their place when you click one key! There should be the "button clicked effect" while respecting the spaces. I hope that the code is clear enough: I divided the calculator in two parts, the screen and the keyboard. You can find my problem in the keyboard section!

Thank you!

**EDIT** I've just edited the code with the solution that I was looking for! Check the edit for the details!

```js
const keys = document.querySelectorAll('#keys-container div');
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('mousedown', () => key.classList.add('press-div')
));
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('mouseup', () => key.classList.remove('press-div')
));
```

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

body > div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}



#display-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 142px;
    width: 440px;
}
#display-border {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 80px;
    width: 410px;

}
#display {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 70px;
    width: 400px;
}




#keyboard {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 420px;
    width: 440px;
}
#keys-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    gap: 12px;
    height: 377px;
    width: 410px;
}
#keys-container div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    /*box-sizing: border-box;*/
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    height: 60px;
    width: 80px;
    transition: 0.01s;
}
#keys-container .press-div {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 2px;
    
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div id="display-container">
        <div id="display-border">
            <div id="display"></div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="keyboard">
        <div id="keys-container">
            <div>ON/C</div>
            <div>7</div>
            <div>4</div>
            <div>1</div>
            <div>0</div>
            <div>CE</div>
            <div>8</div>
            <div>5</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>&#8901;</div>
            <div>&#177;</div>
            <div>9</div>
            <div>6</div>
            <div>3</div>
            <div>&#61;</div>
            <div>&#247;</div>
            <div>&#215;</div>
            <div>&#8722;</div>
            <div style="height: 136px">&#43;</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your current CSS `border` (as well as `padding`) is not counted in the total element height, this results in *jitter* when changing the `border-bottom` value.

Adding `* { box-sizing: border-box }` to your CSS will solve the problem as border and padding values will now be counted as part of the total element width/height. Reference [MDN: box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

Check the first line of CSS in the **the snippet**:

```js
const keys = document.querySelectorAll('#keys-container div');
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('mousedown', () => key.classList.add('press-div')));
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('mouseup', () => key.classList.remove('press-div')));
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

body>div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#display-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 142px;
  width: 440px;
}

#display-border {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80px;
  width: 410px;
}

#display {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 70px;
  width: 400px;
}

#keyboard {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 420px;
  width: 440px;
}

#keys-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  gap: 12px;
  height: 377px;
  width: 410px;
}

#keys-container div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /*box-sizing: border-box;*/
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  height: 60px;
  width: 80px;
  transition: 0.01s;
}

#keys-container .press-div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="display-container">
  <div id="display-border">
    <div id="display"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="keyboard">
  <div id="keys-container">
    <div>ON/C</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>0</div>
    <div>CE</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>&#8901;</div>
    <div>&#177;</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>&#61;</div>
    <div>&#247;</div>
    <div>&#215;</div>
    <div>&#8722;</div>
    <div style="height: 136px">&#43;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Yeah I've already tryed to use the `box-sizing: border-box` property (I turned off its effect in my original snippet wrapping it inside a comment) but it doesn't work and the effect gets lost. The effect that I'd like is that, when you click it, the div has to move down a little bit while losing the extra bottom margin AND WITHOUT modify it's dimension. You don't get this effect with the `box-sizing: border-box` because with this the extra paddings and margins that you add get summed to the height and width of the box and so modify its original dimension. **continue**

Comment: In this way, when you go to get rid off the extra margin, you lose the effect because you see the div changing its dimension (because if the `box-sizing: border-box`. BUT I found the solution! Try to add `margin-top: 2px` in the class the gets added when you click the div (and of course delete the `box-sizing: border-box`). You get the effect that I was looking for!

Comment: I edited the code so you can see my solution!

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you decrease the border size on the bottom of the key, you decrease the height of the content, moving everything under it upwards to fill the 2px space.

Just keep the space consistent by replacing that 2px border perhaps with a margin instead.

```css
#keys-container .press-div {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

Comment: I felt that it has something to do with the concept of the boxes in CSS and so with borders, padding and margins. Inspired by your comments, I found the solution! You don't have to add the `margin-bottom` but instead the `margin-top`. With the bottom you have an effect like `box-sizing: border-box` which I don't want. I want my div that moves a little bit down when you click it WITHOUT changing its dimension and WITHOUT creating that whole movement like before. And I achived all this with `margin-top`! Try it! Thank you!

Comment: I edited the code so you can see my solution!